# MathML and LaTeX conversion required in htlatex

Tags: automation, htlatex

I have required all the `display equations` should be convert to `MathML` options and some inline-equations need to convert in `text mode` format. This two types of conversion is possible in `htlatex`?. For Example, below the first paragraph content should be convert to `text-mode` format (like <i>a</i><sup>2</sup>)..

And the 2nd paragraph content, when-ever `superscript` and `subscript` is need to convert to `mathml` format.

And all the display equations need to convert to `MathML` Format.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
This the sample paragraph text here. This should be convert to normal text mode option $a^2$.

This should be convert to MathML inline equation option $a^2_2$.

The below equation should be convert to MathML option.
\begin{equation}
\sum^2_{i=1} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, it is not possible, with `mathml` option all math commands are redefined to produce `mathml` code. In theory, you could redefine them in inline math environment to produce `html` instead, but it would prevent `mathml` for more complicated expressions.

The only solution is to use custom commands for simple sub- and super-scripts. Create files `simplescript.sty`:

```
\newcommand\sisp[2]{\ensuremath{{#1}^{#2}}}
\newcommand\sisb[2]{\ensuremath{{#1}_{#2}}}
\endinput
```

and `simplescript.4ht`

```
\renewcommand\sisb[2]{\HCode{<i>}#1\HCode{</i><sub>}#2\HCode{</sub>}}
\renewcommand\sisp[2]{\HCode{<i>}#1\HCode{</i><sup>}#2\HCode{</sup>}}
```

and modify your source code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{simplescript}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
This the sample paragraph text here. This should be convert to normal text mode
option \sisp{a}{2} and \sisb{a}{2}.

This should be convert to MathML inline equation option $a^2_2$.

The below equation should be convert to MathML option.
\begin{equation}
\sum^2_{i=1} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

and this is the result:

```xml
<!--l. 5--><p class="noindent" >This the sample paragraph text here. This should be convert to normal text mode
option <i>a</i><sup>2</sup> and <i>a</i><sub>2</sub>.
</p><!--l. 8--><p class="indent" >   This should be convert to MathML inline equation option
<!--l. 8--><math 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"  
display="inline" ><msubsup><mrow 
><mi 
>a</mi></mrow><mrow 
><mn>2</mn></mrow><mrow 
><mn>2</mn></mrow></msubsup 
></math>.
</p><!--l. 10--><p class="indent" >   The below equation should be convert to MathML option. </p>
```